# Do we know the name of the, presumably doomed, ship in Against the Tide of Years?

Tags: emberverse

In *Against the Tide of Years* (March of Year 9 A.E.) the flotilla that took the first expeditionary force to Babylon gets hammered by a storm off the African coast while heading back to Nantucket, the *Chamberlain* survives and in Chapter Eleven they encounter another flotilla vessel, much worse off than they are (it's described as "Hull down. No masts"), somewhere south of Madagascar. I've read the series a number of times but can't seem to find any clues, does anyone know, or even have a shortlist of possibilities, the identity of this vessel?

Comment: It would help if your title was a bit more descriptive that "this ship". Clickbait-y titles are usually frowned upon

Comment: @Edlothiad I am open to suggestions, it was the best my sleep deprived brain could produce on short notice.

Comment: "Do we know the name of the ship *described as "Hull Down. No masts"*"? Or something to that effect.

Answer (score 1):

A bit earlier in Ch11, Alston gives orders to keep a careful lookout. The passage goes on "That was all she could do for the rest of the flotilla.- - Either the sea had eaten them or not".

This would suggest that it was the wreck of another member of the flotilla. But as far as I can ascertain we are never told so. Alston says "I'd better take a look" but when next we hear of the *Chamberlain* it is at Durban. There is no mention of the other ship, or of any survivors from it, which would seem to imply that there were none. Unless I have overlooked it, there seems to be nothing further.

Comment: Dammit that's what I thought too but I hoped someone had noticed something I missed, I might have to brave Facebook long enough to ask Mr Stirling himself, not that he tends to answer this kind of question.

Answer (score 0):

So it turns out you have to read *two* books not one to answer this question, and the answer is we don't know what ship it is but it's NOT a named Islander vessel and thus certainly not a member of the flotilla, unless they recycled a name without mentioning it:

The make up of the Islander Flotilla that goes to Babylon *is* given but much earlier, in Chapter 5 of *Against the Tide of Years*, it consists of five ships. The *Eagle* commanded by Captain Nguyen, two "Clipper-Frigates" (*Chamberlain* and *Lincoln*); Marion is on the heavily damaged *Chamberlain* when she sees the unknown vessel, *Lincoln* under the command Victor Ortiz gets home and back to Babylon with a second load of weapons and other equipment early in 10 A.E. while the *Chamberlain* is still being repaired on the coast of Africa. The other two ships are the colliers *Frederick Douglass* (which stays at Mauritius Base) and *Harriet Tubman* which is patrolling off Tartessos in October 10 A.E. So the whole Flotilla eventually gets home which the ship seen south of Madagascar does not so it may be an Islander merchant vessel or it could be sailing out of Tartessos.